# Task LongRunning side effects?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

If a Task is created using the LongRunning option are there any side effects as they do not use the ThreadPool

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105988/task-parallel-library-taskcreationoptions-longrunning-option-and-threadpool does auto completion work when you enter question title in your browser ? :)

Comment: I found it! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**. Side effect is that: *if you have a million tasks, you could potentially create a million threads.*

Need to take into account that each thread will bring its **memory overhead** and **context switching overhead.** Memory overhead is not that small, we are talking **a few MB** here so even with thousands of items, you could run into trouble.

Answer (score 27):

The `LongRunning` option is a hint to the scheduler which means it *may* choose to execute the `Task` on a non-ThreadPool Thread (if it's the thread-pool backed `DefaultScheduler` it most likely will). One side-effect of the `LongRunning` option is that Task Inlining is disallowed for that Task. This means that if the `LongRunning` Task creates other nested or child Tasks and calls `Wait` on any of those Tasks, they will always be executed on a different Thread rather than being inlined (i.e. run on the same Thread performing the `Wait`).

In the context of other people's answers it's worth noting that creating a large number of Tasks that take a long time to complete **without** the `LongRunning` hint is still likely to cause an escalation in the number of Threads due to the Thread Injection algorithm that the `DefaultScheduler` uses. The algorithm doesn't distinguish between Threads in the pool that are blocked and those that have been running a work item for a long time and in both cases can respond by injecting more Threads into the pool to try to increase work-throughput.

Comment: Reflectoring shows that the hint, as of .NET 4.0, is always obeyed.

Answer (score 5):

LongRunning tasks, indicates that the global and local queues will be bypassed, so as to prevent it from blocking the other threads coming after it in the local queue.

That means, if you have lot of these Long Running tasks, it could create more threads than normal.

You can see in the answers on this question some of the drawbacks:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/8304b44f-0480-488c-93a4-ec419327183b

Comment: Updated to be a bit clearer (and hopefully more inline with what the MSDN says)