# Why is async not allowing for parallel processing unless I manually create new threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I wrote a Windows service, and I would like it to work using the same exact logic that it currently has, but process everything in parallel.

The real codebase is fairly abstracted and private, so I can't post the source here but here's the gist of it.

The app is a persistent process scheduler. It leverages EntityFramework 6 to scan a database for records detailing (among other things): 1.) a path for a process to run, 2.) a date/time to run the process and 3. the scheduled frequency that it is on.

### Basic Functionality

1. It loops through the database for active records and returns all scheduled job details
2. Checks the date and time against the current date and time, within a buffer
3. If the job should run, it has been using either `new Process().Start(...)` with the path from the record, initializes the process if the file is found and is executable, and then wait for an exit or the configured timeout threshold to elapse
4. The exit code or lack of one (in the event of hanging processes) for each process run is what single-handedly determines if the record remains active and continues to get cycled and re-scheduled dynamically into the future, or instead, deactivated with errors logged to the associated record in the DB.
5. The process continues perpetually unless explicitly stopped.

### Currently Working in Parallel (1000% faster, but it looks like it is possibly skipping records!). Maybe I need to add a lock before accessing the db?

> As it turns out I was `using (var process) {...}` and it was throwing that it was being disposed. After staring at the code a few days, I saw this stupid mistake I had made trying to be tidy ;p

```
var tasks = new List<Thread>;

schedules.ForEach(schedule => {
  // I have also tried ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkerItem(...) but then I read its basically long-hand for Task.Run() and I don't think it was working the same as new Thread using this pattern.

  var thread = new Thread(() => await ProcessSchedule(schedule));

  // Actually using slim semaphore in wild, but for simplicty sake...
  thread.Start();
  threads.Add(thread);
});

// Before exiting...
while (!threads.All(instance => !instance.IsAlive))
{
  await Delay(debounceValue);

  continue;
}
```

### Working in Sequence without Issue Besides it's Blocking Slowness...

```
var tasks = new List<Task>;

schedules.ForEach(schedule => {
  // I have also tried to just await this here, but that obviously will block anything on the same thread, so I add the tasks to a list a wait for completion after the loop is complete and the processes are working on their own process. 
  tasks.Add(ProcessSchedule(schedule));
});

// Before exiting... 
// I expected this to work but it still seems to go record by record :*(
// Also tried using Task.Run(() => await task(...)) with no luck...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

> Note: I am passing the list of tasks or threads up another level in the real code so it can process and be awaited on while everything is working but this is some simplified borderline-psuedo code strictly for demonstrating the concept I am struggling with as concise as possible

### Inside of ProcessSchedule

Async method which starts a new process and waits for an exit. When one is received, a success or exit is written to the database using EntityFramework 6 on the schedule record which drove the process for this instance being parsed and evaluated. EG:

```
 new Process(startInfo).Start();

 // Monitor process, persist exit state via 

dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
process.StandardError += handleProcExitListener;
process.StandardOutput += handleProcExitListener;
process.Exited += (...) => handleProcExitListener(...);
```

**I can say that:**

I have no non-awaited async methods unless its using `await Task.Run(MethodAsync)`, is in `Main(argz)` `await Task.WhenAll(task);`, etc.

Is async-await blocking me because `DbContext` is not thread safe by default or something? If this is the case, would someone please verify how I can achieve what I am looking for?

I have tried a number of techniques, but I am not able to get the application to run each process simultaneously, then wait and react upon the end state after spawning the processes, unless I use multithreading (new Thread directly maybe also using ThreadPool).

I have not had to resort to using threads in a while, mostly since the introduction of async-await in C#. Therefore, I am questioning myself using it without first fully understanding why. I would really appreciate some help grasping what I am missing.

It seems to me async is just a fancy pattern and facades for easy access to state-machine characteristics. Why then when I researched the subject did I just read that using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkerItem(...)` is rather obsolete since TPL `async/await`. If async/await does not give you new threads to work with, is running a process in parallel possible without it? Also, these processes take anywhere from 10min to 45min each to run. So you can see the importance of running them all together.

Since I am stuck with .NET 4.8, I, unfortunately, cannot use the async version of `WaitForExitAsync()` introduced in v5+.

**Solution**
I modeled a solution from the following [Async process start and wait for it to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611094/async-process-start-and-wait-for-it-to-finish)

```
public static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(this Process process, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        ManualResetEvent processWaitObject = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        processWaitObject.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    RegisteredWaitHandle registeredProcessWaitHandle = null;
    registeredProcessWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        processWaitObject,
        delegate(object state, bool timedOut)
        {
            if (!timedOut)
            {
                registeredProcessWaitHandle.Unregister(null);
            }

            processWaitObject.Dispose();
            tcs.SetResult(!timedOut);
        },
        null /* state */,
        timeout,
        true /* executeOnlyOnce */);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the line `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500);` at the start of the program, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, should this go with `new Thread()` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkerItem` or just the latter?

Comment: My theory is that the `ThreadPool` becomes saturated, and you are observing the effects of this situation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623048/does-whenall-add-unnecessary-delay-also-what-is-causing-the-discrete-spikes-in/72624593#72624593) is a loosely related recent answer about the `ThreadPool`, and what it means to be saturated. My suggestion is to try configuring the `ThreadPool` so that it creates instantly new threads on demand, in order to confirm or rule out this theory. This is suggested  as a troubleshooting attempt, not as a fix.

Comment: Threads created manually with the `Thread` constructor do not affect the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), and are not affected by the `ThreadPool` activity, or its configuration. At least not directly. At the end of the day all threads are micromanaged by the OS, and share the same underlying resources (the CPUs of the machine).

Comment: `var thread = new Thread(() => await ProcessSchedule(schedule));` does not do what you think it does. The continuation is in the ThreadPool, the thread itself will quickly finish. You should probably convert whatever it is you are doing in EF to a bulk operation, which likely won't need parallelizing. Database calls are a bad example for parallelizing, because they are normally IO-bound and tend to just interfere with each other.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the solution from the question. Including answers inside the questions is frowned upon here. If you want you can post the solution as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which [you have already done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723451/11178549), so I don't see the point of repeating the same solution in two places.

Comment: Also, since the solution is apparently the `Process.WaitForExitAsync`, the problem is also apparently the `Process.WaitForExit`. There is no reference to the `Process.WaitForExit` in the question though. It is something that we have to guess, without it being visible anywhere. This is something that needs to be improved IMHO, by editing the question, and mentioning what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have omitted some of the `Process` code, I'm assuming that you are calling the blocking method `Process.WaitForExit` instead of the async equivalent of it. I have created a mock type solution and this runs in parallel.

```cs
private static async Task RunPowershellProcess()
{
    using var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.Exited += (a, _) =>
    {
        var p = a as Process;
        Console.WriteLine(p?.ExitCode);
    };
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start();
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>(10);
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        tasks.Add(RunPowershellProcess());
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing to the `Exited` event, and don't just move the event-handling code after the `await process.WaitForExitAsync()`?

Comment: Fair call. I just used what OP has in there already.

Comment: The OP is not a seasoned async-await expert, and as a consequence they are mixing things up. We are supposed to show them how to simplify their code, as part of the async-await transition. 

Comment: To be fair, suggesting setting the min threads for threadpool to overcome blocking isn't helping OP transition to async-await either.

Comment: I've suggested the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` for troubleshooting purposes only, not as a permanent solution. The correct solution is what you have shown in this answer (the `Process.WaitForExitAsync`). It requires .NET 5 or later though.

Comment: It's pretty easy to wrap the `Exited` event with a `TaskCompletionSource` to achieve this without .NET5 or higher

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not so simple. Take a look at this: [Process.WaitForExit() asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470256/process-waitforexit-asynchronously). There is a race condition regarding insta-completing processes, as well as the possibility of firing the `Exited` event before all handlers of the `Process.OutputDataReceived` event have completed. The new `WaitForExitAsync` API solves robustly these problems.

Comment: Thanks yall! Unfortunately, I am stuck in the stone ages bc I am currently employed by a very security-minded company. Because the bleeding or even remotely cutting edge is deemed "risky", I am stuck in .Net 4.72 and do not have the ability to use `process.WaitForExitAsync()` unless I roll my own like I am attempting to do. Great suggestion though, should have pointed this out in my OP. @JohanP I am gonna try rolling my own this way @TheadorZoulias Had to catch up sleep from being stuck on this, trying the threading config shortly