# Is it normal that WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() is the diagnostics hottest path

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on an application that does high frequency sequential calculations. Since in some parts of the process we have I/O tasks, all methods are written async. Since the application was facing some performance issues I ran diagnostics while debugging and found out that the WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() is the hottest path of the application as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

We know that this method is responsible for executing work items queued to the thread pool.
Is this report showing that we are abusing the async/await all the way in the application or it can be seen as normal?
In such case what would you suggest to improve the performance?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say. This normally happens when too many tasks are queued to be run at once. Are you overusing `Task.Run` somewhere? Or perhaps blocking in the middle of a task (rather than using `await`)?

Comment: I use Task.Run here and there but not sure how much they impact. Do you this is more because of using Task.Run than having all hundreds of methods async/await? The calculation process has relatively long stack chains of many small methods that are all async.

Comment: This is a likely problem if there are a lot of tasks that are doing synchronous blocking, rather than doing `await`. You say "calculation" is it a complex CPU-bound operation? Please show some relevant code.

Comment: this is kind of a big application. I can't really choose a part that could give you the bigger picture. 
Yes there are several methods that do cpu-bound operations especially using Linq to iterate over arrays.  I would have guessed that these parts would consume the most CPU but as we see it's the thread pool. 
As I said the calculations part involves long async/await call stacks (chain of async methods calling each other and awaiting). So my question is this behavior because of the long asnyc/await stacks or something else like using Task.Run as you suggested?

Comment: The async/await itself should not cause this, if anything the opposite, because as soon as you hit an `await` it will offload the task completely, not using any thread at all. If you have long-running CPU-bound operations then maybe use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37611613/14868997 Note that this is not a panacea, it should only be used on very computationally heavy tasks, not tasks that are inherently IO bound, such as disk or network access.