# Cancelling a threadpool workitem with Thread.Interrupt

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

We are using the TPL to queue long-running tasks into the threadpool.
Some of the tasks can block for some time, so we are using the following pattern to cancel them:

```
private void RunAction(Action action, CancellationTokenSourceWithException cts)
{

    try
    {
        s_logger.Info("Starting action on thread ID: {0}", Utils.GetCurrentNativeThreadId());

        Thread taskThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        cts.Token.Register(() => InterruptTask(taskThread));

        s_logger.Info("Running next action");
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        cts.Cancel(e);
        throw;
    }
```

This way, calling `cts.Cancel()` will cause the task thread to be interrupted in case it is blocking.
This, however, has led to a problem: we don't know if the thread actually got the ThreadInterruptedException or not. It is possible that we call `Thread.Interrupt()` on it, but the thread will run to completion and the task will simply end. In that case, the threadpool thread will have a ticking bomb in the form of the ThreadInterruptedException, and whenver another task runs on this thread and attempts to block, it will get this exception.

A `Thread.ResetInterrupted()` method (similar to `Thread.ResetAbort()`) would be helpful here, but it does not seem to exist. We can use something like the following:

```
try
{
    someEvent.Wait(10);
}
catch (ThreadInterruptedException) {}
```

To swallow the ThreadInterruptedException, but it looks ugly.

Can anyone suggest an alternative? Are we wrong to be calling Thread.Interrupt on threadpool threads? It seems like the easiest way to cancel tasks: cooperative cancellation using events etc. are much more cumbersome to use, and have to propagate into all classes that we use from the task.

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot do this because you don't know if/when the thread pool's threads will block when not running your own code!**

Apart from the problems you mentioned, if a thread decides to block while not running your own code then the `ThreadInterruptException` will be unhandled and the app will immediately terminate. This is something you cannot work around with a `try`/block/`catch` guard because there is a race condition: the guard might have just completed when `Thread.Interrupt` is called, so if the runtime decides to have the thread block at that point you 'll get a crash.

So using `Thread.Interrupt` is not a viable option and you will definitely have to set up cooperative cancellation.

Apart from that, you should probably not be using the thread pool for these tasks in the first place (although there's not enough data to be . Quoting the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If you have **short tasks** that require background processing, the
>   managed thread pool is an easy way to take advantage of multiple
>   threads.
>
> There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and
>   manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:
>
> - ...
> - You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large
>     number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from
>     starting.
> - ...

You might therefore want to consider using a thread pool of your own (there is an apparently very reputable implementation [here](http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: I am using the TPL, not the threadpool directly. I was under the impression that the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag is specifically designed for long-running tasks. Also, even if I roll out my own threadpool, I will run into this same problem.

Comment: @telewin: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105988/taskcreationoptions-longrunning-option-and-threadpool. It seems that `LongRunning` will create separate threads, but AFAIK this is not documented anywhere so it might not be desirable to depend on it. The cancellation problem is a separate issue than the pool problem of course.

Comment: Indeed - these are different problems. I am more interested in the cancellation problem. I am using TPL to run long running tasks, and in that sense I don't care how it schedules them. What I want to do is "handle" the Thread.Interrupt request in my action thread, whether it blocks or not.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You need to pass a CancellationToken to the action being called and act on it when cancellation is signalled. Messing with TPL threads with `Interrupt` is definitely the wrong action to take and will leave TPL in a "confused" state. Adopt the cancellation pattern all the way.

Comment: I agree that this approach would work, but it can significantly complicate the code. For example, I cannot use any `lock() {}` statements in my code, and I have to convert them all to `Monitor` (or `WaitHandle`, or whatever). I was hoping Thread.Interrupt would let me write cleaner code, and I think that swallowing the `ThreadInterruptedException` as I suggested in the original question, would solve the problem you described, no?