# Rx TaskPoolScheduler vs EventLoopScheduler, memory usage

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm trying to do a POC on the numerous independent data feeds. Sort of classical observer style application. Number of data feeds might vary from few hundred to few thousand, and numbers of observers might vary somewhat from 2 to 20000. Here's a quick example of simple data feed observable mock-up:

```
    public class FeedMockUp
    {
        private readonly IScheduler observerScheduler;
        private readonly Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        private readonly Subject<double> sourceObservable;
        private readonly IObservable<double> testedObservable;

        public FeedMockUp(IScheduler observerScheduler)
        {
            this.observerScheduler = observerScheduler;
            sourceObservable = new Subject<double>();

            testedObservable =
                Observable.Create<double>(x =>
                {
                    var underlyingSourceDisposable =
                        sourceObservable
                            .Subscribe(_ => x.OnNext(rnd.NextDouble()));
                    return underlyingSourceDisposable;
                });
        }

        public IDisposable SubscribeToUnderlyingFeed(int numberOfSubscribers)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubscribers; i++)
            {
                disposable.Add(testedObservable
                    .ObserveOn(observerScheduler)
                    .Subscribe(_ => Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)));
            }

            return disposable;
        }

        public void PushNewFeed()
        {
            sourceObservable.OnNext(rnd.NextDouble());
        }
    }
```

While I was playing around with the shedulers in order to improve the throughput of observables update I have noticed that while using `EventLoopScheduler` memory consumption of the application having 100 data feeds with 1000 observers was quite constant, for 1000 observers it being ~100Mb and  growing linearly when adding new observers to the mix.

However when I've tried using TaskPoolScheduler, on x86 process I've started getting `OutOfMemoryException` exceptions and on x64 process memory consumption exploded, or rather, became quite indeterminate ranging anywhere from 1Gb to 2Gb for just 500 observers and growing almost exponentially with new observers in the mix.

Here's the code I've been using for testing. Can you see what's wrong with it? Why such a difference in performance? Guessing, there's some internal copying/queuing involved here, but it's just my guess. Ideally I'd like to find out what's happening here without diving to RX code base...

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int displayItemCount = 100;
        const int callbackCount = 500;

        //var rtScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(); 
        var rtScheduler = TaskPoolScheduler.Default;
        var rtFeeds = new List<FeedMockUp>();
        for (int i = 0; i < displayItemCount; i++)
        {
            var mockFeed = new FeedMockUp(rtScheduler);
            mockFeed.SubscribeToUnderlyingFeed(callbackCount);
            rtFeeds.Add(mockFeed);
        }
        foreach (var rtFeedMockUp in rtFeeds)
        {
            rtFeedMockUp.PushNewFeed();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Memory used for feed {0} mockups with {1} observers / callbacks. Memory {2} Mb",
            displayItemCount, callbackCount, Environment.WorkingSet / (1024 * 1024));
Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `ObserveOn` with `TaskPoolScheduler` is essentially going to create a [LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) task for each observer.

And the default `TaskScheduler` ends up [creating a `Thread` for each `LongRunning` tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105988/taskcreationoptions-longrunning-option-and-threadpool).

And each Thread reserves roughly 1MB for its stack.

So, 500 observers using the `TaskPoolScheduler` will reserve at least 500MB.  You can see where this is going...

The `EventLoopScheduler`, on the other hand, runs on a single thread.  So using `ObserveOn` with this scheduler effectively just adds an entry to the scheduler's work queue.  This entry is much much smaller than the 1MB cost of a Thread.

So, the `EventLoopScheduler` is much more memory efficient for this scenario, but it also notifies the observers serially and if there are alot of observers and the source is producing at a high frequency, then you'll start to accumulate a buffer of unsent events.

The `TaskPoolScheduler` is less memory efficient but will notify observers concurrently and thus can potentially handle higher frequency events than the `EventLoopScheduler` by utilizing all of the cores on your machine.

Comment: You could also create one `EventLoopScheduler` per core and implement a load balancer on the entry point; e.g., round-robin scheduler selection. This could be wrapped inside its own `IScheduler` implementation so that you only need to pass around a single ref.

Comment: Quite amusing watching the memory go exponential when the thread pool starts ramping up it's thread count! http://imgur.com/NGnDOH0 Fixed that typo btw Dave. Also, I've used that approach you suggested successfully in the past.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to use `TaskPoolScheduler.Default.DisableOptimizations(typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning))`. The EventLoopScheduler is a good alternative if you don't mind loosing parallelism.

This option is preferable in case you still want to execute work in parallel but want to use a thread pool thread.