# Confusion regarding threads and if asynchronous methods are truly asynchronous in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I was reading up on async/await and when `Task.Yield` might be useful and came across [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645024/when-would-i-use-task-yield)  I had a question regarding the below from that post:

> When you use async/await, there is no guarantee that the method you
>   call when you do await `FooAsync()` will actually run asynchronously.
>   The internal implementation is free to return using a completely
>   synchronous path.

This is a little unclear to me probably because the definition of asynchronous in my head is not lining up.

In my mind, since I do mainly UI dev, async code is code that does not run on the UI thread, but on some other thread.  I guess in the text I quoted, a method is not truly async if it blocks on any thread (even if it's a thread pool thread for example).

**Question:**

If I have a long running task that is CPU bound (let's say it is doing a lot of hard math), then running that task asynchronously must be blocking some thread right?  Something has to actually do the math.  If I await it then some thread is getting blocked.

What is an example of a truly asynchronous method and how would they actually work?  Are those limited to I/O operations which take advantage of some hardware capabilities so no thread is ever blocked?

Comment: The mandatory reading: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: I like your question, but the title "Asynchronous methods in .Net/C#" is too general IMO.

Comment: @Julian I updated OP's question to be more specific

Comment: If it's CPU bound then the CPU is running on a thread, yes - all code runs on a thread. If it's waiting for a packet from the network, *that is not code* and therefore does not need to run on a thread. (There's code somewhere to start waiting and stop waiting, but the actual waiting is not code)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

> This is a little unclear to me probably because the definition of asynchronous in my head is not lining up.

Good on you for asking for clarification.

> In my mind, since I do mainly UI dev, async code is code that does not run on the UI thread, but on some other thread.

That belief is common but false.  There is no requirement that asynchronous code run on any second thread.

Imagine that you are cooking breakfast. You put some toast in the toaster, and while you are waiting for the toast to pop, you go through your mail from yesterday, pay some bills, and hey, the toast popped up.  You finish paying that bill and then go butter your toast.

Where in there did you hire a second worker to watch your toaster?

You didn't.  Threads are workers.  Asynchronous workflows can happen all on one thread. The point of the asynchronous workflow is to *avoid* hiring more workers if you can possibly avoid it.

> If I have a long running task that is CPU bound (let's say it is doing a lot of hard math), then running that task asynchronously must be blocking some thread right? Something has to actually do the math.

Here, I'll give you a hard problem to solve.  Here's a column of 100 numbers; please add them up by hand.  So you add the first to the second and make a total. Then you add the running total to the third and get a total.  Then, oh, hell, the second page of numbers is missing.  Remember where you were, and go make some toast.  Oh, while the toast was toasting, a letter arrived with the remaining numbers.  When you're done buttering the toast, go keep on adding up those numbers, and remember to eat the toast the next time you have a free moment.

Where is the part where you hired another worker to add the numbers?  **Computationally expensive work need not be synchronous, and need not block a thread**.  The thing that makes computational work potentially asynchronous is the ability to stop it, remember where you were, go do something else, remember what to do *after that*, and resume where you left off.

Now it is certainly *possible* to hire a second worker who does nothing but add numbers, and then is fired. And you could ask that worker "are you done?" and if the answer is no, you could go make a sandwich until they are done.  That way both you and the worker are busy.  But there is not a *requirement* that asynchrony involve multiple workers.

> If I await it then some thread is getting blocked.

NO NO NO. This is the most important part of your misunderstanding. `await` does not mean "go start this job asynchronously".  `await` means "I have an asynchronously produced result here that might not be available. If it is not available, *find some other work to do on this thread* so that we are **not** blocking the thread.  Await is the **opposite** of what you just said.

> What is an example of a truly asynchronous method and how would they actually work? Are those limited to I/O operations which take advantage of some hardware capabilities so no thread is ever blocked?

Asynchronous work often involves custom hardware or multiple threads, but it need not.

Don't think about *workers*. Think about *workflows*. The essence of asynchrony is *breaking up workflows into little parts* such that *you can determine the order in which those parts must happen*, and then *executing each part in turn*, but *allowing parts that do not have dependencies with each other to be interleaved*.

In an asynchronous workflow you can easily detect *places in the workflow where a dependency between parts is expressed*.  Such parts are marked with `await`.  That's the meaning of `await`: the code which follows depends upon this portion of the workflow being completed, so if it is not completed, go find some other task to do, and come back here later when the task is completed. The whole point is to keep the worker working, even in a world where needed results are being produced in the future.

Comment: I find it slightly amusing that we've created this thread abstraction over the concept of "just doing stuff" (like interrupts and DPCs), and now we've built an abstraction of "just doing stuff" based on threads.

Comment: @immibis How are interrupts and DPCs an abstraction? They are tools, not abstractions. `Task` is an abstraction.

Comment: AFAIK JavaScript is both single-thread and emphasizes asynchrony.

Comment: @Euphoric you may want to re-read the comment, I didn't say interrupts and DPCs were abstractions.

Answer (score 27):

> I was reading up on async/await

May I recommend my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)?

> and when Task.Yield might be useful

Almost never. I find it occasionally useful when doing unit testing.

> In my mind, since I do mainly UI dev, async code is code that does not run on the UI thread, but on some other thread.

[Asynchronous code can be threadless](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> I guess in the text I quoted, a method is not truly async if it blocks on any thread (even if it's a thread pool thread for example).

I would say that's correct. I use the term "truly async" for operations that do not block any threads (and that are not synchronous). I also use the term "fake async" for operations that *appear* asynchronous but only work that way because they run on or block a thread pool thread.

> If I have a long running task that is CPU bound (let's say it is doing a lot of hard math), then running that task asynchronously must be blocking some thread right? Something has to actually do the math.

Yes; in this case, you would want to define that work with a synchronous API (since it is synchronous work), and then you can call it from your UI thread using `Task.Run`, e.g.:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => MySynchronousCpuBoundCode());
```

> If I await it then some thread is getting blocked.

No; the thread pool thread would be used to run the code (not actually blocked), and the UI thread is asynchronously waiting for that code to complete (also not blocked).

> What is an example of a truly asynchronous method and how would they actually work?

`NetworkStream.WriteAsync` (indirectly) asks the network card to write out some bytes. There is no thread responsible for writing out the bytes one at a time and waiting for each byte to be written. The network card handles all of that. When the network card is done writing all the bytes, it (eventually) completes the task returned from `WriteAsync`.

> Are those limited to I/O operations which take advantage of some hardware capabilities so no thread is ever blocked?

Not entirely, although I/O operations are the easy examples. Another fairly easy example is timers (e.g., `Task.Delay`). Though you can build a truly asynchronous API around any kind of "event".

Comment: I think that Task.Yield can be useful to effectively prevent inlining of an awaited task. If you want the awaited task to definitely execute after the current (async) method returns, then awaiting Task.Yield inside the awaited task will effectively push the awaited task further down on the scheduler (i.e. not inlined). -- yes?

Comment: @sjb-sjb: `Task.Yield` forces asynchrony, yes. But when do you need to do this? Almost never. It is occasionally useful when unit testing. If you find you need it in your production code, then take a long, hard look at the design of your production code and see what improvements can be made.

Comment: Yeah, I agree generally but it does still happen. I encountered it recently in a situation too complicated to explain here but I would say the design was valid. Although normally one could use Run to get the required asynchrony, I could not do that in this situation because it had to be done on the current (UI) thread. I have also seen other situations in which things on the UI thread were happening in the wrong order and could be fixed using Yield.

Comment: The first example was: running something on the UI thread after the current method has exited. For that there is another way, namely using Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync. 

However the other example was: let something else run on the UI thread before the rest of this method runs (with "this method" being a UI callback). For that I think Task.Yield is easiest although it might also work to write a separate method and schedule it with Dispatcher.RunAsync. 

So I guess you are right. One can use Dispatcher.RunAsync in the cases where I was thinking of Task.Yield.

Comment: @sjb-sjb: `Task.Yield` doesn't work for that, due to the way message queues work on Windows.

Comment: I managed to get into a deadlock by awaiting Task.Yield, a seemingly paradoxical outcome which however follows logically from awaiting a more or less random task. 
I'm agreeing with you more and more on this one !!

Comment: @sjb-sjb: As a general rule, I prefer `Task.Run` to offload from the UI thread, and `IProgress<T>` for UI updates. In situations where the UI updates take too long for responsiveness, then UI virtualization is usually a better solution than a "yield to the message queue" kind of approach. That said, if you do want to "yield to the message queue", pass a small nonzero value to `Task.Delay` instead of using `Task.Yield`, e.g., `await Task.Delay(50);`.

Answer (score 10):

> > When you use async/await, there is no guarantee that the method you call when you do await FooAsync() will actually run asynchronously. The internal implementation is free to return using a completely synchronous path.
>
> This is a little unclear to me probably because the definition of
> asynchronous in my head is not lining up.

This simply means there are two cases when calling an async method.

The first is that, upon returning the task to you, the operation is already completed -- this would be a synchronous path. The second is that the operation is still in progress -- this is the async path.

Consider this code, which should show both of these paths. If the key is in a cache, it is returned synchronously. Otherwise, an async op is started which calls out to a database:

```
Task<T> GetCachedDataAsync(string key)
{
    if(cache.TryGetvalue(key, out T value))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(value); // synchronous: no awaits here.
    }
    
    // start a fully async op.
    return GetDataImpl();
    
    async Task<T> GetDataImpl()
    {
        value = await database.GetValueAsync(key);
        cache[key] = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

So by understanding that, you can deduce that in theory the call of `database.GetValueAsync()` may have a similar code and itself be able to return synchronously: so even *your* async path may end up running 100% synchronously. But your code doesn't need to care: async/await handles both cases seamlessly.

> If I have a long running task that is CPU bound (let's say it is doing a lot of hard math), then running that task asynchronously must be blocking some thread right? Something has to actually do the math. If I await it then some thread is getting blocked.

Blocking is a well-defined term -- it means your thread has yielded its execution window while it waits for something (I/O, mutex, and so on). So your thread doing the math is not considered blocked: it is actually performing work.

> What is an example of a truly asynchronous method and how would they actually work? Are those limited to I/O operations which take advantage of some hardware capabilities so no thread is ever blocked?

A "truly async method" would be one that simply never blocks. It typically ends up involving I/O, but it can also mean `await`ing your heavy math code when you want to your current thread for something else (as in UI development) or when you're trying to introduce parallelism:

```
async Task<double> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    double x = await ReadXFromFile();
    
    Task<double> a = LongMathCodeA(x);
    Task<double> b = LongMathCodeB(x);
    
    await Task.WhenAll(a, b);
    
    return a.Result + b.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This topic is fairly vast and several discussions may arise. However, using `async` and `await` in C# is considered asynchronous programming. However, how asynchrony works is a total different discussion. Until .NET 4.5 there were no async and await keywords, and developers had to develop directly against the [Task Parallel Librar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.110).aspx)y (TPL). There the developer had full control on when and how to create new tasks and even threads. However, this had a downside since not being really an expert on this topic, applications could suffer from heavy performance problems and bugs due to race conditions between threads and so on.

Starting with .NET 4.5 the async and await keywords were introduced, with a new approach to asynchronous programming. The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use `Task.Run` to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available.

The async-based approach to asynchronous programming is preferable to existing approaches in almost every case. In particular, this approach is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations because the code is simpler and you don't have to guard against race conditions. You can read more about this topic [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx).

I don't consider myself a C# black belt and some more experienced developers may raise some further discussions, but as a principle I hope that I managed to answer your question.

Comment: While informative this does not answer the OP's question. The OP's question, IMO, is specific enough that an answer containing a summary of recent history in C# asynchronous programming and a linking referring to the OP to the MSDN on C# Asynchronous Programming with Async is not the answer the OP is looking for and I think it is clear the OP question might still remain even after reading MSDN on C#Asynchronous Programming with Async

Comment: it is good that you pointed out that the async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created but that still doesn't fully answer the OPs question I think

Comment: In a certain way, I assume you're right. However, IMO this question can't be really answered, or at least not the way it is formulated right now. What "heavy maths" means is something subjective to everybody's imagination. In most of the cases async and await will do the job, it won't block the main thread so the application will still be responsive till it "awaits" a result. Thank you for your feedback. Hope I'll do better next time :)

Comment: I think the OPs question really is asking why: "there is no guarantee that the method you call when you do await FooAsync() will actually run asynchronously" is true though the OP maybe doesn't give a good example, using "heavy math" scenario

Answer (score 6):

### Asynchronous does not imply Parallel

Asynchronous only implies concurrency. In fact, even using explicit threads doesn't guarantee that they will execute simultaneously (for example when the threads affinity for the same single core, or more commonly when there is only one core in the machine to begin with).

Therefore, you should not expect an asynchronous operation to happen simultaneously to something else. Asynchronous only means that it will happen, eventually *at another time* (*a*(greek) = without, *syn* (greek) = together, *khronos* (greek) = time. => *Asynchronous* = not happening at the same time).

Note: The idea of asynchronicity is that on the invocation you do not care when the code will actually run. This allows the system to take advantage of parallelism, if possible, to execute the operation. It may even run immediately. It could even happen on the same thread... more on that later.

When you `await` the asynchronous operation, you are creating *concurrency* (*com* (latin) = together, *currere* (latin) = run. => "Concurrent" = *to run together*). That is because you are asking for the asynchronous operation to reach completion before moving on. We can say the execution converges. This is similar to the concept of joining threads.

---

### When asynchronous cannot be Parallel

> When you use async/await, there is no guarantee that the method you call when you do await FooAsync() will actually run asynchronously. The internal implementation is free to return using a completely synchronous path.

This can happen in three ways:

1. It is possible to use `await` on anything that returns `Task`. When you receive the `Task` it could have already been completed.

   Yet, that alone does not imply it ran synchronously. In fact, it suggest it ran asynchronously and finished before you got the `Task` instance.

   Keep in mind that you can `await` on an already completed task:

   ```
   private static async Task CallFooAsync()
   {
       await FooAsync();
   }

   private static Task FooAsync()
   {
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }

   private static void Main()
   {
       CallFooAsync().Wait();
   }
   ```

   Also, if an `async` method has no `await` it will run synchronously.

   Note: As you already know, a method that returns a `Task` may be waiting on the network, or on the file system, etc… doing so does not imply to start a new `Thread` or enqueue something on the `ThreadPool`.
2. Under a synchronization context that is handled by a single thread, the result will be to execute the `Task` synchronously, with some overhead. This is the case of the UI thread, I'll talk more about what happens below.
3. It is possible to write a custom [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) to always run tasks synchronously. On the same thread, that does the invocation.

   Note: recently I wrote a custom `SyncrhonizationContext` that runs tasks on a single thread. You can find it at [Creating a (System.Threading.Tasks.)Task scheduler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349352/creating-a-system-threading-tasks-task-scheduler/349369#349369). It would result in such `TaskScheduler` with a call to [`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

   The default `TaskScheduler` will enqueue the invocations to the [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). Yet when you await on the operation, if it has not run on the `ThreadPool` it will try to remove it from the `ThreadPool` and run it inline (on the same thread that is waiting... the thread is waiting anyway, so it is not busy).

   Note: One notable exception is a `Task` marked with [`LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). [`LongRunning` `Task`s will run on a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105988/taskcreationoptions-longrunning-option-and-threadpool).

---

### Your question

> If I have a long running task that is CPU bound (let's say it is doing a lot of hard math), then running that task asynchronously must be blocking some thread right? Something has to actually do the math. If I await it then some thread is getting blocked.

If you are doing computations, they must happen on some thread, that part is right.

Yet, the beauty of `async` and `await` is that the waiting thread does not have to be blocked (more on that later). Yet, it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot by having the awaited task scheduled to run on the same thread that is waiting, resulting in synchronous execution (which is an easy mistake in the UI thread).

One of the key characteristics of `async` and `await` is that they take the [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) from the caller. For most threads that results in using the default `TaskScheduler` (which, as mentioned earlier, uses the `ThreasPool`). However, for UI thread it means posting the tasks into the message queue, this means that they will run on the UI thread. The advantage of this is that you don’t have to use [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) to access UI components.

Before I go into how to `await` a `Task` from the UI thread without blocking it, I want to note that it is possible to implement a `TaskScheduler` where if you `await` on a `Task`, you don’t block your thread or have it go idle, instead you let your thread pick another `Task` that is waiting for execution. *When I was [backporting Tasks for .NET 2.0](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot) I experimented with this.*

> What is an example of a truly asynchronous method and how would they actually work? Are those limited to I/O operations which take advantage of some hardware capabilities so no thread is ever blocked?

You seem to confuse *asynchronous* with *not blocking a thread*. If what you want is an example of asynchronous operations in .NET that do not require blocking a thread, a way to do it that you may find easy to grasp is to use [continuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `await`. And for the continuations that you need to run on the UI thread, you can use [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Do not implement fancy spin waiting**. And by that I mean using a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Application.Idle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle(v=vs.110).aspx) or anything like that.

When you use `async` you are telling the compiler to rewrite the code of the method in a way that allows breaking it. The result is similar to continuations, with a much more convenient syntax. When the thread reaches an `await` the `Task` will be scheduled, and the thread is free to continue after the current `async` invocation (out of the method). When the `Task` is done, the continuation (after the `await`) is scheduled.

For the UI thread this means that once it reaches `await`, it is free to continue to process messages. Once the awaited `Task` is done, the continuation (after the `await`) will be scheduled. As a result, reaching `await` doesn’t imply to block the thread.

Yet blindly adding `async` and `await` won’t fix all your problems.

I submit to you an experiment. Get a new Windows Forms application, drop in a [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), and add the following code:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await WorkAsync(5000);
        textBox1.Text = @"DONE";
    }

    private async Task WorkAsync(int milliseconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
```

It blocks the UI. What happens is that, as mentioned earlier, `await` automatically uses the `SynchronizationContext` of the caller thread. In this case, that is the UI thread. Therefore, `WorkAsync` will run on the UI thread.

This is what happens:

- The UI threads gets the click message and calls the click event handler
- In the click event handler, the UI thread reaches `await WorkAsync(5000)`
- `WorkAsync(5000)` (and scheduling its continuation) is scheduled to run on the current synchronization context, which is the UI thread synchronization context… meaning that it posts a message to execute it
- The UI thread is now free to process further messages
- The UI thread picks the message to execute `WorkAsync(5000)` and schedule its continuation
- The UI thread calls `WorkAsync(5000)` with continuation
- In `WorkAsync`, the UI thread runs `Thread.Sleep`. The UI is now irresponsive for 5 seconds.
- The continuation schedules the rest of the click event handler to run, this is done by posting another message for the UI thread
- The UI thread is now free to process further messages
- The UI thread picks the message to continue in the click event handler
- The UI thread updates the textbox

The result is synchronous execution, with overhead.

Yes, you should use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. That is not the point; consider `Sleep` a stand in for some computation. The point is that just using `async` and `await` everywhere won't give you an application that is automatically parallel. It is much better to pick what do you want to run on a background thread (e.g. on the `ThreadPool`) and what do you want to run on the UI thread.

Now, try the following code:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Work(5000));
        textBox1.Text = @"DONE";
    }

    private void Work(int milliseconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
```

You will find that await does not block the UI. This is because in this case [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) is now running on the `ThreadPool` thanks to [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx). And thanks to `button1_Click` being `async`, once the code reaches `await` the UI thread is free to continue working. After the `Task` is done, the code will resume after the `await` thanks to the compiler rewriting the method to allow precisely that.

This is what happens:

- The UI threads gets the click message and calls the click event handler
- In the click event handler, the UI thread reaches `await Task.Run(() => Work(5000))`
- `Task.Run(() => Work(5000))` (and scheduling its continuation) is scheduled to run on the current synchronization context, which is the UI thread synchronization context… meaning that it posts a message to execute it
- The UI thread is now free to process further messages
- The UI thread picks the message to execute `Task.Run(() => Work(5000))` and schedule its continuation when done
- The UI thread calls `Task.Run(() => Work(5000))` with continuation, this will run on the `ThreadPool`
- The UI thread is now free to process further messages

When the `ThreadPool` finishes, the continuation will schedule the rest of the click event handler to run, this is done by posting another message for the UI thread. When the UI thread picks the message to continue in the click event handler it will updates the textbox.

Comment: "a" is 'Greek' for without. Not Latin ;)

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis fixed

Answer (score 4):

Here's asynchronous code which shows how async / await allows code to block and release control to another flow, then resume control but not needing a thread.

```
public static async Task<string> Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Foo");
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("I'm Back");
    return "Foo";
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new Task(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        var f = Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("After Foo");        
        var r = await f;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    });
    t.RunSynchronously();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

So it's that releasing of control and resynching when you want results that's key with async/await  ( which works well with threading )

NOTE: No Threads were blocked in the making of this code :)

I think sometimes the confusion might come from "Tasks" which doesn't mean something running on its own thread.   It just means a thing to do, async / await allows tasks to be broken up into stages and coordinate those various stages into a flow.

It's kind of like cooking, you follow the recipe.  You need to do all the prep work before assembling the dish for cooking.  So you turn on the oven, start cutting things, grating things, etc.   Then you await the temp of oven and await the prep work.   You could do it by yourself swapping between tasks in a way that seems logical (tasks / async / await),  but you can get someone else to help grate cheese while you chop carrots (threads) to get things done faster.

Answer (score 4):

Stephen's answer is already great, so I'm not going to repeat what he said; I've done my fair share of repeating the same arguments many times on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere).

Instead, let me focus on one important abstract things about asynchronous code: it's not an absolute qualifier. There is no point in saying a piece of code is asynchronous - it's always asynchronous *with respect to something else*. This is quite important.

The purpose of `await` is to build synchronous workflows on top of asynchronous operations and some connecting synchronous code. Your code *appears* perfectly synchronous<sup>1</sup> to the code itself.

```
var a = await A();
await B(a);
```

The ordering of events is specified by the `await` invocations. B uses the return value of A, which means A must have run before B. The method containing this code has a  synchronous workflow, and the two methods A and B are synchronous with respect to each other.

This is very useful, because synchronous workflows are usually easier to think about, and more importantly, a lot of workflows simply *are* synchronous. If B needs the result of A to run, it *must* run after A<sup>2</sup>. If you need to make an HTTP request to get the URL for another HTTP request, you must wait for the first request to complete; it has nothing to do with thread/task scheduling. Perhaps we could call this "inherent synchronicity", apart from "accidental synchronicity" where you force order on things that do not need to be ordered.

You say:

> In my mind, since I do mainly UI dev, async code is code that does not run on the UI thread, but on some other thread.

You're describing code that runs asynchronously with respect to the UI. That is certainly a very useful case for asynchrony (people don't like UI that stops responding). But it's just a specific case of a more general principle - allowing things to happen out of order with respect to one another. Again, it's not an absolute - you want *some* events to happen out of order (say, when the user drags the window or the progress bar changes, the window should still redraw), while others must *not* happen out of order (the Process button must not be clicked before the Load action finishes). `await` in this use case isn't *that* different from using `Application.DoEvents` in principle - it introduces many of the same problems and benefits.

This is also the part where the original quote gets interesting. The UI needs a thread to be updated. That thread invokes an event handler, which may be using `await`. Does it mean that the line where `await` is used will allow the UI to update itself in response to user input? No.

First, you need to understand that `await` uses its argument, just as if it were a method call. In my sample, `A` must have already been invoked before the code generated by `await` can do anything, including "releasing control back to the UI loop". The return value of `A` is `Task<T>` instead of just `T`, representing a "possible value in the future" - and `await`-generated code checks to see if the value is already there (in which case it just continues on the same thread) or not (which means we get to release the thread back to the UI loop). But in either case, the `Task<T>` value itself *must* have been returned from `A`.

Consider this implementation:

```
public async Task<int> A()
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000);

  return 42;
}
```

The caller needs `A` to return a value (a task of int); since there's no `await`s in the method, that means the `return 42;`. But that cannot happen before the sleep finishes, because the two operations are synchronous with respect to the thread. The caller thread will be blocked for a second, regardless of whether it uses `await` or not - the blocking is in `A()` itself, not `await theTaskResultOfA`.

In contrast, consider this:

```
public async Task<int> A()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);

  return 42;
}
```

As soon as the execution gets to the `await`, it sees that the task being awaited isn't finished yet and returns control back to its caller; and the `await` in the caller consequently returns control back to *its* caller. We've managed to make some of the code asynchronous with respect to the UI. The synchronicity between the UI thread and A was accidental, and we removed it.

The important part here is: there's no way to distinguish between the two implementations from the outside without inspecting the code. Only the return type is part of the method signature - it doesn't say the method will execute asynchronously, only that it *may*. This may be for any number of good reasons, so there's no point in fighting it - for example, there's no point in breaking the thread of execution when the result is already available:

```
var responseTask = GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

// Do some CPU intensive task
ComputeAllTheFuzz();

response = await responseTask;
```

We need to do some work. Some events can run asynchronously with respect to others (in this case, `ComputeAllTheFuzz` is independent of the HTTP request) and are asynchronous. But at some point, we need to get back to a synchronous workflow (for example, something that requires both the result of `ComputeAllTheFuzz` and the HTTP request). That's the `await` point, which synchronizes the execution again (if you had multiple asynchronous workflows, you'd use something like `Task.WhenAll`). However, if the HTTP request managed to complete before the computation, there's no point in releasing control at the `await` point - we can simply continue on the same thread. There's been no waste of the CPU - no blocking of the thread; it does useful CPU work. But we didn't give any opportunity for the UI to update.

This is of course why this pattern is usually avoided in more general asynchronous methods. It is useful for some uses of asynchronous code (avoiding wasting threads and CPU time), but not others (keeping the UI responsive). If you expect such a method to keep the UI responsive, you're not going to be happy with the result. But if you use it as part of a web service, for example, it will work great - the focus there is on avoiding wasting threads, not keeping the UI responsive (that's already provided by asynchronously invoking the service endpoint - there's no benefit from doing the same thing again on the service side).

In short, `await` allows you to write code that is asynchronous with respect to its caller. It doesn't invoke a magical power of asynchronicity, it isn't asynchronous with respect to everything, it doesn't prevent you from using the CPU or blocking threads. It just gives you the tools to easily make a synchronous workflow out of asynchronous operations, and present part of the whole workflow as asynchronous with respect to its caller.

Let's consider an UI event handler. If the individual asynchronous operations happen to not need a thread to execute (e.g. asynchronous I/O), part of the asynchronous method may allow other code to execute on the original thread (and the UI stays responsive in those parts). When the operation needs the CPU/thread again, it may or may not require the *original* thread to continue the work. If it does, the UI will be blocked again for the duration of the CPU work; if it doesn't (the *awaiter* specifies this using `ConfigureAwait(false)`), the UI code will run in parallel. Assuming there's enough resources to handle both, of course. If you need the UI to stay responsive at all times, you cannot use the UI thread for any execution long enough to be noticeable - even if that means you have to wrap an unreliable "usually asynchronous, but sometimes blocks for a few seconds" async method in a `Task.Run`. There's costs and benefits to both approaches - it's a trade-off, as with all engineering :)

---

1. Of course, perfect as far as the abstraction holds - every abstraction leaks, and there's plenty of leaks in await and other approaches to asynchronous execution.
2. A sufficiently smart optimizer might allow some part of B to run, up to the point where the return value of A is actually needed; this is what your CPU does with normal "synchronous" code ([Out of order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)). Such optimizations *must* preserve the appearance of synchronicity, though - if the CPU misjudges the ordering of operations, it must discard the results and present a correct ordering.